# Calculator reads keyboard input multiple times

Tags: windows-8.1, calculator

When I try to enter the values from the keyboard, they appear several times instead of one. 
Does anyone have the same bug?
When I click on the input panel with the mouse, everything works fine.

E.g. I type 2, and textbox show me 22 or 222

Comment: Is the key repeat rate/delay too fast?

Comment: Nope. This is strange, because 
in all applications it`s working properly. I have two keyboards (notebook and wireless). E.g. I type 2, and textbox show me 22 or 222.

Comment: Normally, this is a keyboard issue, which would appear everywhere.  If I'm reading your question and comment right, it sounds like you are seeing it only in the calculator.  It that correct?

Comment: Yes, I see it only in calculator. In all other applications it`s working properly. I tried to turn off the wireless keyboard, but it does not solve the issue.